# Saving drupal webform data to a database

Tags: php, database, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

Im using Drupal version 6.19 and the webform module in Drupal to create forms.I have two forms on my site.When the user submits the form, where in the drupal database are the entries saved for each form ?

Please help
Thank You

Answer (score 3):

Just take a look at its database schema in `webform.install`.

```
...
$schema['webform_submitted_data'] = array(
    'description' => 'Stores all submitted field data for webform submissions.',
    'fields' => array(
      'nid' => array(
        'description' => 'The node identifier of a webform.',
        'type' => 'int',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => 0,
      ),
      'sid' => array(
        'description' => 'The unique identifier for this submission.',
        'type' => 'int',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => 0,
      ),
      'cid' => array(
        'description' => 'The identifier for this component within this node, starts at 0 for each node.',
        'type' => 'int',
        'size' => 'small',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => 0,
      ),
      'no' => array(
        'description' => 'Usually this value is 0, but if a field has multiple values (such as a time or date), it may require multiple rows in the database.',
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => 128,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => '0',
      ),
      'data' => array(
        'description' => 'The submitted value of this field, may be serialized for some components.',
        'type' => 'text',
        'size' => 'medium',
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
    ),
    'indexes' => array(
      'nid' => array('nid'),
      'sid_nid' => array('sid', 'nid'),
    ),
    'primary key' => array('nid', 'sid', 'cid', 'no'),
  );
...
```

Comment: Can you tell me about the schema of the these tables, `webform_submissions` and `webform_roles` ? Thanks.

Comment: Hey, I just want to know the schema of the two tables above. If you could please tell me. Thank you.

Comment: Table schemas are all defined in `webform.install` file, have a look there.

Comment: Oh, I see. I think I have read that but unfortunately forgot that part. Thanks again mate. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

First, log in to mysql

After, use database_name;

You must replace with the name of the database

Then, show tables;

The last sentence will show you the tables of tha database

Now, select * from webform_submitted_data;

You should be able to see the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can also view submitted data by navigating to Content Management > Webforms. I believe the data is serialized in the database, so if you have large forms its not an easy read.